# Is the Trickmaster an optional boss?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I just finished the Wonderland world of Kingdom Hearts however towards the end of the level I found the Cheshire cat sitting on the table, if I talk to him it will start the [Trickmaster](http://www.khwiki.net/Trickmaster) boss battle. However if I ignore him and drink the potion that makes me large again and continue back to the Rabbit Hole area I can save then go onto to another world.

So, is the Trickmaster an optional boss or will I have to go back later on to beat him?

Comment: The optional bosses in KH are kurt zisa, phantom, ice titan, & sephiroth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trickmaster is *not* optional. If you don't defeat it, the keyhole will not appear, and you won't be able to seal Wonderland.

Sealing the keyhole has no real impact on Wonderland. You'll still be able to fight heartless, find White Mushrooms, and track down any items up may have missed. You will still be able to access Wonderland.

As SirDuckDuck points out, failure to seal all worlds will not allow you to actually beat the game.

Comment: And what would happen if you not seal all worlds? I think another world would not unlock, but not sure.

Comment: What happens when I seal Wonderland is it no longer enterable? this my first time playing KH.

Comment: Actually  SirDuckduck said he wasn't sure, and he even asked you the same thing I did above. _EDIT: thanks_